# SQL: Issue with WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Interests.Interest_name, Impressions.Count 
FROM Interests 
WHERE Vertical_name = 'Retail'
INNER JOIN Impressions ON Interests.Interest_Name = Impressions.Interest_Name;
```

The above query generates the error

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Inner'.

If I remove the `WHERE` clause it works perfectly OK. I am not sure if there is an issue with the syntax?

Comment: The where clause should come after the join. Voting to close as simple syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` condition needs to go after joins, try to move it to the end:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Interests.Interest_name,Impressions.Count FROM Interests 
Inner Join Impressions ON Interests.Interest_Name = Impressions.Interest_Name
WHERE Vertical_name = 'Retail';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the Syntax is just wrong. You have to move the `WHERE` after your `JOIN`

For example:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Interests.Interest_name,Impressions.Count 
FROM Interests 
INNER JOIN Impressions 
    ON Interests.Interest_Name = Impressions.Interest_Name
WHERE Vertical_name = 'Retail';
```

If you tried to pre-filter your table `Interests` you can do that this way:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Interests.Interest_name,Impressions.Count 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Interests 
    WHERE Vertical_name = 'Retail'
    ) as Interests
INNER JOIN Impressions 
    ON Interests.Interest_Name = Impressions.Interest_Name;
```

Just a hint after all. I would suggest you, to use aliases for every table. It will improve the reading and will save you if you need to rename a table.

Answer (score 1):

The `where` goes *after* the `from` clause.  And `join` is part of the `from` clause.

Your query would be easier to write and to read with aliases:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT i.Interest_name, i.Count
FROM Interests i Inner Join
     Impressions im
     ON i.Interest_Name = im.Interest_Name;
WHERE Vertical_name = 'Retail';
```

If you don't need the `DISTINCT`, then you should remove it.  It only hurts performance.

In fact, a better way to write this query is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT i.Interest_name, i.Count
FROM Interests i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Impressions im
              WHERE i.Interest_Name = im.Interest_Name
             )
WHERE i.Vertical_name = 'Retail';
```

This assumes that `Vertical_Name` is in `Interests`.  Otherwise, it would go in the subquery.